# Deleting items from object (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, set

I have a set object ... if **num** is found in **numberSet**, I am deleting that value from object set using .delete function. *Additionally*, I would like to delete anything before it (in this case '6' or first entry or any number lower than num) ... Is that possible using delete?

```
const numberSet = new Set(['6', '7', '8']);
const num = '7'

if (numberSet.has(num)) {
 numberSet.delete(num)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to play around with prototype method, you can add your custom method that does the trick. **THIS IS AN ANITPATTERN THOUGH**

```
Set.prototype.deleteBefore = function(val) {
   if(this.has(val)) {
     for(const el of this) {
       if(el === val) break;
       this.delete(el);
     } 
   }
}


// Now you can use this simply by
let numberSet = new Set(['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']);
numberSet.deleteBefore('8'); // { '8', '9', '10' }
```

Comment: I would never suggest to add functions to prototypes. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287827/whats-wrong-about-extending-a-class-with-prototype-methods
There a several save ways to accomplish the same like extending the needed class, using a function, using call() or bind() or even add the method as an instance property.

Comment: Also this will fail if the added values are not sorted. from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set :  You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. SO if you insert 8 before 4 your code will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Using a simple while loop and `Set.values()`.

```js
const numberSet = new Set(['6', '7', '8']),
      num = '7',
      values = numberSet.values();

while(numberSet.has(num)){ 
   numberSet.delete(values.next().value)
}



console.log('Set size =',numberSet.size) 
console.log('values remaining ', ...numberSet)
```